# Cauchy–Riemann differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Hi I'm stuck on this problem, given the following and I have to find the derivatives using cauchy riemann and state the points where it is analytic:

$$ f(z) = (z^2-iz+6)^8$$

This is what I have so far:

$$ f(z) = ((x^2 - y^2 +y +6)+i(2xy-x)^8$$

From this I would say:

$$ u(x,y) = (x^2 - y^2 +y +6)^8$$
$$ v(x,y) = (2xy-x)^8$$

Im confused about this power to 8? I dont think I'm expected to expand this, any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $z^2, -iz$ and $8$ are holomorphic, then the sum too, and the product too.

Comment: ie, is a polynomial

Comment: I dont know what means

Comment: Does this seem right? $$ f(z) = 8(z^2 -iz+6)^7(2z-i) $$ There for it is analytical everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how it is expected of you to do this, but I'll offer some possibilities.

First, one can show using the definition of the derivative that any polynomial with complex coefficients is holomorphic everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$, and that the multiplication of holomorphic functions is again holomorphic. So, since $f(z)$ is just a power of a polynomial, it is holomorphic everywhere.

Furthermore, you can prove again with the definition of the derivative that both the power rule and chain rule for differentiation hold for complex variables. Thus, you can find $f'(z)$ just like you would normally find it if $z$ and all the coefficients where real.

That being said, if you are asked to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations it's not as straightforward. The problem is that

$$f(z) = \left[(x^2-y^2+y+6) + i(2xy-x)\right]^8 \neq (x^2-y^2+y+6)^8 + i(2xy-x)^8$$

so you can't conclude that the functions $u$ and $v$ that you have written are indeed the real and imaginary parts of $f$. What you could do is use the following alternate form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

This is what the Cauchy-Riemann equations look like before you plug in $f = u + iv$ and obtain the familiar formulas. If you use this, however, you don't have to determine the real and imaginary parts of your function. You can just use it as it is after plunging in $z=x+iy$. If the above equality holds (and if the derivatives are continuous, which they are), then $f$ is holomorphic and

$$ f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $$